# How to track keydown event on browser?

Tags: browser, keypress, keydown, keylogger, usability-testing

Does anyone know if there is a tool or app that lets one capture keydown/keypress events in a browser across a page that isn't mine? I don't necessarily need to know what key was pressed.

I can't use jQuery because I can't run a cross-domain keydown/keypress request either.

I've considered using keylogger tools but they generally don't have a live update mechanism where I can retrieve the keys pressed in a stored file (many solutions I've come across only generate the file when requested, which makes sense).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you serious? You're asking to log keypresses on a site you don't own?

Comment: Purely within the browser....no. If you're operating within a company network and are able to deploy your own apps to all the users, you could probably work something out. Even then it's probably a bit of a legal gray area.

Comment: Well the intent isn't malicious - I want to be able to record the amount of keydowns a person is doing in a particular browser session, purely for interaction purposes (ie. is the person doing more browsing or typing)?

Comment: Also, this would be done in a controlled lab environment, not massively deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a usability testing software, I assume they record and do stats on  things such as mouse, key presses, etc.

I've never used software like this, but here are some pointers:

- http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2009/01/26/cheap-and-free-alternatives-to-morae-usability-testing-software/
- https://ux.stackexchange.com/